# Помогите сделать красивый вывод массива структур с++

Tags: c++, структуры, структуры-данных, динамические-структуры

Нужно сначала ввести массив структур а затем сделать вывод. Я его реализовал но выводит довольно криво, можете подсказать как это красиво оформить?
Вот мой код вывода:

```
void vivod(sports *x, int j) {
cout << endl << "Имя" << "     " << "Фамилия"  << "     " << "Рост" << "     " << "Вес" << "     " << "Дата рожд." << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
    cout << x[i].name << "     " << x[i].fam << "     " << x[i].rost << "     " << x[i].ves << "     " << x[i].data << endl;
}
```

}
[image: Вот как выводит у меня]

Comment: [iomanip](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) вам в помощь!

Comment: Почитал описание и не совсем понял, что именно оттуда надо взять. Можешь конкретнее подсказать какие функции и методы оттуда надо юзать?

Comment: `setw()` - ширину поля, например.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Но лучше с манипулятором left ( выравнивать слева)

Comment: Если использовать вывод строго C++, то `iomanip` и `setw`, но я бы рекомендовал воспользоваться С библиотекой `stdio.h` и использовать возможности функции `fprintf`